# CSSTransition height animation and double code

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, reactcsstransitiongroup, react-transition-group

having trouble figuring out how can i fix issue with animating height 
 or fixing duplicated code

Ideally i would have someting like this, but the problem with this approach is, when `editMode` is `false` wrapping div doesn't exist any more, if i understood correct.
[codesandbox example no1 here!](https://codesandbox.io/s/m3lllv794y)

While on this [codesandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/8lxj0rpo78) i have duplicated code which is not ideal imo.

Im new to all of this and stuck with this one for days now.

Sorry for broken english, not my native

Comment: can you please more elaborate your problem with the code section that you are facing problem ? if possible create a different small demo on jsfiddle. Thank You.